# plotly-express figure color legend should display only integer values

Tags: python-3.x, choropleth, plotly-express

A graph created with plotly express using a [choropleth map](https://plotly.com/python/choropleth-maps/) shows distribution of `count` values associated to the regions of Italy:

```python
import pandas as pd
import requests
import plotly.express as px

data = {'regions' : ['Piemonte', 'Trentino-Alto Adige', 'Lombardia', 'Puglia', 'Basilicata', 
           'Friuli Venezia Giulia', 'Liguria', "Valle d'Aosta", 'Emilia-Romagna',
           'Molise', 'Lazio', 'Veneto', 'Sardegna', 'Sicilia', 'Abruzzo',
           'Calabria', 'Toscana', 'Umbria', 'Campania', 'Marche'],
        'counts' : [3, 3, 4, 2, 0,
                    4, 4, 0, 0,
                    1, 1, 0, 3, 4, 4,
                    3, 4, 3, 2, 4]}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)

# Read the geojson data with Italy's regional borders [enter image description here][2]from github
repo_url = 'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/datajournalism-it/48e29e7c87dca7eb1d29/raw/2636aeef92ba0770a073424853f37690064eb0ea/regioni.geojson'
italy_regions_geo = requests.get(repo_url).json()

fig = px.choropleth(data_frame=df, 
                    geojson=italy_regions_geo, 
                    locations='regions', # name of dataframe column matching the region names
                    featureidkey='properties.NOME_REG',  # path to field in GeoJSON feature object with which to match the values passed in to locations
                    color='counts',
                    color_continuous_scale="Magma",
                    scope="europe",
                   )
fig.update_geos(resolution=50, 
                showcountries=False, 
                showcoastlines=False, 
                fitbounds="locations",
                showland=False)

fig.update_layout(margin={"r":0,"t":0,"l":0,"b":0})
fig.show()
fig.write_image("./italy.png")
```

when the maximum value of `count` is four, the figure color legend will include labels with decimals, which is not needed, given that values should be treated as integers. Decimals disappear as soon as the maximum value of `count` is 5, or larger.
[image: Map of Italy realised with plotly-express choroplet]
How do I control the appearance of decimals in the figure color legend?

Comment: Something like this, perhaps: layout = go.Layout(yaxis=dict(tickformat=".00%"))

Comment: Does this require the figure to be created using `plotly.graph_objects`? This picture was defined using `plotly.express.choropleth`

Comment: `yaxis` may be not involved in the legend.  Following the `layout` definition by @ASH and issuing `fig.update_layout(layout,` yields no error, but no effects either on the colormap tick marks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- it's documented here https://plotly.com/python/reference/layout/coloraxis/#layout-coloraxis-colorbar-dtick
- hence one additional layout instruction below

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
import plotly.express as px

data = {'regions' : ['Piemonte', 'Trentino-Alto Adige', 'Lombardia', 'Puglia', 'Basilicata', 
           'Friuli Venezia Giulia', 'Liguria', "Valle d'Aosta", 'Emilia-Romagna',
           'Molise', 'Lazio', 'Veneto', 'Sardegna', 'Sicilia', 'Abruzzo',
           'Calabria', 'Toscana', 'Umbria', 'Campania', 'Marche'],
        'counts' : [3, 3, 4, 2, 0,
                    4, 4, 0, 0,
                    1, 1, 0, 3, 4, 4,
                    3, 4, 3, 2, 4]}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)

# Read the geojson data with Italy's regional borders [enter image description here][2]from github
repo_url = 'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/datajournalism-it/48e29e7c87dca7eb1d29/raw/2636aeef92ba0770a073424853f37690064eb0ea/regioni.geojson'
italy_regions_geo = requests.get(repo_url).json()

fig = px.choropleth(data_frame=df, 
                    geojson=italy_regions_geo, 
                    locations='regions', # name of dataframe column matching the region names
                    featureidkey='properties.NOME_REG',  # path to field in GeoJSON feature object with which to match the values passed in to locations
                    color='counts',
                    color_continuous_scale="Magma",
                    scope="europe",
                   )
fig.update_geos(resolution=50, 
                showcountries=False, 
                showcoastlines=False, 
                fitbounds="locations",
                showland=False)

fig.update_layout(margin={"r":0,"t":0,"l":0,"b":0})
fig.update_layout(coloraxis={"colorbar":{"dtick":1}})
fig.show()
```